# QImage: recoloring an image + alpha + lightness

Tags: c++, image, qt

Using Qt 5.4.1.

A grey image is given. It contains alpha channel as well.
The lightness (like in HSL) of the grey color varies.
An RGB value is given.
What i want to do is to recolor an image considering alpha channel (only touch pixels that has alpha > 0) and lightness (apply lightness to the given rgb color, where lightness = 0 will not change the color).

I was trying to do it without lightness first with the following code:

```
void SkinPreviewWindow::recolorCircle(QImage img, int r, int g, int b) {
    //QImage alpha = img.alphaChannel();
    for (int y = 0; y < img.height(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < img.width(); x++) {
            int a = qAlpha(img.pixel(x,y));
            if (a > 0) {
                img.setPixel(x, y, QColor(r, g, b, a).rgba());
                //alpha.setPixel(x, y, a);
            }
        }
    }
    //img.setAlphaChannel(alpha);
}
```

The other version i had was the same code if you uncomment the commented lines and change the `img.setPixel(x, y, QColor(r, g, b, a).rgba())` line to `img.setPixel(x, y, QColor(r, g, b).rgb())`
Neither worked, still getting a grey image.

If it's important, the image will be drawn to another image after that, and then resulting picture will be  translated to QPixmap and applied to a label on the form.

Is there an easy way to do that? I'm not very familiar with image processing. Also, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried passing a reference to the image rather than a copy?

Comment: Ohhh derp. I somehow missed in. Thanks. The code above works now But the question is still open because i don't know how to apply the lightness.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean by applying the lightness, but maybe you just want to multiply the given r, g, b by the r, g, b of the image pixels, perhaps something like `newr = r * (imgr / 255.0)`?

Comment: What do you mean by "apply the lightness" ? Lightness is a component of the HSL representation of a colour, so either you want to change the lightness of some pixels - in that case, in which way ? -, or you want to do something else depending on the lightness value of pixels ?

Comment: @RetiredNinja it worked as intended, thanks a lot. Now everything works as i wanted.

Comment: @ohyou read about the pitfalls of COW (copy on write idiom) in Qt.